# Arabic disappeared after 12.04 upgrade!

Tags: upgrade, arabic

Well, I was amongst the 12.04 Beta upgraders, and since then I've lost the ability to write in Arabic, and I've been using Ubuntu since 2008 as an only OS without any issues, and been upgrading since then as well, except on this machine, which received one upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 and it got messed up.

I've added Arabic like usual, but it doesn't change with the keyboard's short-cut, and when I do it manually with the Mouse, then it just doesn't work, and it keeps writing in English instead.

I've tried to install some iBus things, and added Arabic-kbd (m17n) but it still remains messy, let alone not having the same layout, and all I want is to get to NORMAL.

So, please, is there any way to reset or initialize these keyboard related settings, so I can get back to normal and stop using the Mac just to type in Arabic, or so often using XP over Vbox?

And please, no Re-install option! I just can't backup all my work right now, and there are a lot of tasks waiting for me to get them done.

Thanks for any kind of support :)

Comment: Fixed anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from Alaswadi Khd. It is very helpful and straightforward·

1. System Setting → Keyboard Layout → then you can add the using + any language.
2. Click on Arabic → Option → Keys to change Layout → Select <kbd>Alt</kbd>+xxx.

You're done.

With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+xxx you will be able to shift the direction.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> you will able to shift the language.